# Pyton script export only haf the information from the json

Tags: python, json, excel

I have python script but when is export the file print only "y", "meas", "label" whitout any data. I have no errors when run the scrpt.
Can you advise to fix that?
I cant post the link and the json.

```py
import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# try this

total_df = pd.DataFrame()
request_list = ["LInk",]

# read each link
for r in request_list:
    resp = requests.get(url=r)
    df = json_normalize(resp.json())

    item_list = df['dataset']
    current_df = pd.DataFrame()
    
    

    for i in item_list:
        try:
            current_df.loc[0,'y'] = i['data'][0]['y']
        except:
            current_df.loc[0,'y'] = np.nan
        try:
            current_df.loc[0,'meas'] = i['meas']
        except:
            current_df.loc[0,'meas'] = np.nan
        try:
            current_df.loc[0,'label'] = i['label']
        except:
            current_df.loc[0,'label'] = np.nan

    total_df = pd.concat([total_df,current_df])


total_df.to_excel('C:/Users/svetl/Onedrive/Desktop/work/output.xlsx',index=False)
```

Comment: Why do you have the try/except clauses?  Those are almost certainly hiding your errors.  Are you 100% confident that the URLs you're reading have those elements in them?

Comment: Please include a __minimal sample__ of the json in your question.

Comment: if you use `try..except` blocks, it's always advised to print out the error. `except Exception as e:  print(e)` instead of the simple `except:`. And as mentioned by Tim Roberts above, this is very likely the root cause of your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the issue is with the way you handle the JSON. The key `dataset` has a list of dict items as value. You try to access the dict item directly while ignoring they are part of a list.

Look at the edited part below, and notice the change from
`i['data'][0]['y']`
to
`i[0]['data'][0]['y']`
(and the other changes when accessing `i`)

```py
    for i in item_list:
        try:
            current_df.loc[0,'y'] = i[0]['data'][0]['y']
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            current_df.loc[0,'y'] = np.nan
        try:
            current_df.loc[0,'meas'] = i[0]['meas']
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            current_df.loc[0,'meas'] = np.nan
        try:
            current_df.loc[0,'label'] = i[0]['label']
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            current_df.loc[0,'label'] = np.nan
```

---

**Sidenote:**

this is deprecated:

```py
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
```

you need to change it to:

```py
from pandas import json_normalize
```